# Is it safe to invalidate a JWT using a blacklist cache?

Tags: security, authentication, web-applications, jwt

The most prevalent examples I have found (as well as code within the JWT-Auth library) provide mechanisms for invalidating JWTs via a black list. If a token needs to be invalidated, it is added to a blacklist, which is essentially just a cache that is subject to volatility.

My concern with my application is that if an attacker received someone's JWT, that if the server were to be forced to restart (or any other circumstance that caused the cache to be wiped) that the JWT would not be invalidated and the attacker could use a previously invalidated token (as unlikely as that may be). I am currently deciding on implementing reference tokens, that way a JWT can be invalidated manually, but it's likely that an attacker has already done their damage by the time you realize it and invalidate your token.

Is it implied that the token will have a life time that is short enough to justify invalidating it based on a cache (that *could be* cleared/wiped/lost)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your threat analysis. Does your app have to be so secure you *absolutely* need to be able to revoke compromized JWT tokens?

Or does keeping the time to live for your tokens short make more sense? If the time to live is for example one hour, chances are significantly higher that the token expired before your customer detected the theft, contacted your support department and got them to revoked the token.

If you still feel you need to be able to revoke JWT tokens, use reference tokens which can be revoked centrally. Having your own blacklist is probably more trouble than it's worth. If you keep the cache in memory, you have to deal with crashes and reboots. If you have multiple servers, you need to to keep multiple caches in sync or use a distributed cache.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, I just needed someone to help validate my assumption.